# How do I embed a file in Swift?

Tags: swift

I need to embed a text file into the source code of a program written in Swift. What's the best way to do that? What if the file was not text, but some binary data. What's the Swift equivalent of the include_str! and include_bytes! macros in Rust?

Comment: You surely have tried _something_. Without showing at least some (research) effort you're highly unlikely to receive an answer here.

Comment: You just don't do such things normally. What's wrong with an external file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift has multi-line string constants, so you can do

```swift
let includeString = """
<your file contents here>
"""
```

There is no built-in equavalant to `include_bytes`, depending on what you need to do exactly it might be easiest to bundle the binary file with your app/program and read it on startup.